# How to get Microsoft Outlook reminder event list on webpage by PHP?

Tags: php, calendar, outlook

I did't not find any solution to get list of outlook calender event list down to webpage by PHP , Is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Adnan hey, are you looking for http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8068-PHP-Access-Microsoft-Exchange-Web-services-via-OWA-API.html